# Perl Parallel::ForkManager - share hash with parrent and merge with exists

Tags: perl

Im begineer in programming languages. First time Im using run_on_finish callback for hashref. Do I do it correctly? Im trying send hash to parrent and merge keys and values with rest values of this hash. I want to get exactly the same hash that I would get without using ForkManager and child processes.

```
use Hash::Merge qw/merge/;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Data::Dumper;
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);
my %hash;

$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
my ($pid,$exit_code,$ident,$exit_signal,$core_dump,$data)=@_;
  %hash = %{ merge( \%hash, \$data->{$i} ) };
  print "TEST: $data->{$i} \n";
});
my @tablica = ('jeden', 'dwa', 'trzy');
foreach (@tablica) {
  my $pid = $pm->start and next;
  $rsdev{$_} = localtime;
  $pm->finish(0, \%rsdev);
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```

output

```
perl "untitled.pl"
TEST:  
TEST:  
TEST:  
$VAR1 = {};
```

Im trying to get output like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'jeden' => 'Mon Mar 26 17:26:01 2018',
          'dwa' => 'Mon Mar 26 17:26:01 2018',
          'trzy' => 'Mon Mar 26 17:26:01 2018',
        };
```

Im dont know why but $data->[0] value is empty. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide some code that can run and shows the problem? The variables $threads @c %rsdev are undefined.

Comment: I fixed. Can You take a look?

Comment: `my ($pid,$exit_code,$ident,$exit_signal,$core_dump,$data)=@_;` should be in the sub.

Comment: `\$data->[0]` looks wrong.

Comment: But how fix it? :D

Comment: I edited question with Your suggestions. I change $data->[0] to $data->{$i}. But im still don't know do I do it correctly. As the question is incomprehensible, write it. I will try to put it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Parallel::ForkManager qw();
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);
my %hash;
$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
    my $data = pop @_;
    %hash = (%hash, %$data);
});
my %rsdev;
for my $i (0..9) {
    my $pid = $pm->start and next;
    $rsdev{$i} = localtime;
    $pm->finish(0, \%rsdev);
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
print Dumper \%hash;
__END__
{
    '9' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018',
    '2' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018',
    '5' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018',
    '0' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018',
    '4' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018',
    '8' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018',
    '3' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018',
    '6' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018',
    '7' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018',
    '1' => 'Mon Mar 26 18:08:40 2018'
}
```

Comment: But about 'pop': Do all will be fine when I will use more variables or hashes on finish (in array) callback? Im talking about something like this: $pm->finish(0, (%rsdev, $variable));

Comment: if each run is returning much less data than you expect in the parent hash, better to do `@hash{ keys %$data } = values %$data;` to merge the new stuff in

Answer (score 1):

- `my (...) = @_;` should be in the sub.
- The value you return is also much more complicated than it needs to be.

Fixed:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);

my %rsdevs;
$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
    my ($pid, $exit_code, $id, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $rsdev) = @_;

    warn("Child $id killed by signal $exit_signal"), return if $exit_signal;
    warn("Child $id exited with error $exit_code"),  return if $exit_code;
    warn("Child $id encountered an unknown error"),  return if !$rsdev;

    $rsdevs{$ident} = $rsdev;
});

my @tablicas = ('jeden', 'dwa', 'trzy');
for my $id (@tablicas) {
   my $pid = $pm->start($id) and next;
   my $rsdev = { ts => "".localtime, foo => rand };
   $pm->finish(0, $rsdev);
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Comment: It dont work: print Dumper \$rsdevs; - $VAR1 = \undef;

Comment: I read the documentation about $ident - my for loop and keys was just an example. In fact, the keys will not be successive numbers just a string. This solution only works with the $i (0..9) loop?

Comment: @F. Grela, Re "*It dont work: print Dumper \$rsdevs; - $VAR1 = \undef;*", There's no var named `$rsdevs` in my code. Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!! We omit them from answers to keep them short. /// The results are stored in `%rsdevs`.

Comment: @F. Grela, `$ident` can be any string that's unique for each worker.

Comment: @F. Grela, In a comment to the other answer, you said you wanted to return multiple values in a hash, so I have updated the answer.

Comment: @F. Grela, You should probably use `time`, not `localtime`. Only use `localtime` when it comes time to output.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I understand, but I do not want the key to be the child ident, I want the key to be a string from array with parrent. Child is irrelevant to me. I asked the question because variables and hashes die with child. I just want to get them in the form they look like without using ForkManager.

I've misspelled my question. I am new and I'm just learning :) I corrected the question.

Comment: Re "*I do not want the key to be the child ident [...] I corrected the question*", The corrected question still uses the child ident as the key.